# Create a spread function using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a `function` as parameter using `Python`, something like:

```
spread(someFunction, [1, true, "Foo", "bar"] )
```

And that should be converted to:

```
someFunction(1, true, "Foo", "bar")
```

But at the moment to test with:

```
test.assert_equals( spread(lambda x,y: x+y , [1,2]) , 3 )
```

My funciton is not working.

Reading the `Python` documentation, I'm trying with:

```
def myfunc(anotherfunc, extraArgs):
    anotherfunc(*extraArgs)
```

But is not working.

some one has an idea about how to use a function as parameter and use the original funciton parameters inside the other function?

Comment: I think you may miss a `return`. `return anotherfunc(*extraArgs)`

Comment: You right! thanks for the help!!! I'm new on python. If you add it as answer I can validate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just miss a `return` in your function.

```
def myfunc(anotherfunc, extraArgs):
    return anotherfunc(*extraArgs)
```